# Variadic function to check equal lengths of STL containers

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I am writing my first variadic function template. I am getting the error `error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:`. Probably I cannot understand some easy concept here. I would like to store all passed in `iterators` in a `vector`. What is the right way to do this?

```
template<typename... Iterator>
bool IsEqualLength(Iterator&... its)
{
    std::vector<Iterator> vec_its {its...};
    int head = vec_its.front().size();

    bool is_diff_size = std::any_of(vec_its.begin(), vec_its.end(), 
        [&head](Iterator& cur){return cur.size() != head;});

    if(is_diff_size)
    {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This fails to compile with (under gcc 4.8.4 on Ubuntu):

```
../proc.h: In function ‘bool IsEqualLength(Iterator& ...)’:
../proc.h:32:24: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
  std::vector<Iterator> vec_its {its...};
                        ^
../proc.h:32:24: note:         ‘Iterator’
../proc.h:35:87: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using two different packs in this statement:

```
std::vector<Iterator> vec_its {its...};
```

`its` is expanded, but `Iterator` isn't a single type... it's a pack too, and you're failing to expand it. Hence the error (which specifically points out `Iterator`).

If all you want is the sizes of the containers, you could just call `size()` on all the passed-in containers (containers, not iterators!) and put that in an array (no need for dynamic allocation):

```
template <typename... Container>
bool isEqualLength(Container&&... cs) {
    size_t sizes[] = {cs.size()...};

    return std::all_of(std::begin(sizes), std::end(sizes),
        [&sizes](size_t cur){return cur == sizes[0]; });
}
```